# increment an iterator c++ after fill with another container

Tags: c++11, vector, iterator

I have a class with vector of string (lines).
I have also iterator for the current line of the vector.

I have a method that fills the lines with another container (also vector)
I want to update my iterator of current line that points to the last element.

I do this and it is working fine in my compiler but in my teacher compiler it does not work.

```
class Document {
...
...
 std::vector<std::string> lines; 
 std::vector<std::string>::iterator currLine;
};

void Document::addLineBefore(std::vector<std::string>::iterator begin, std::vector<std::string>::iterator end)
{
  int n = std::distance(begin,end) -1;

  currLine = (lines.insert(currLine, begin, end)) + n;

}
```

My teacher compiler :

```
*Compile Error:
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp Editor.cpp Document.cpp
Document.cpp: In member function 'void Document::addLineBefore(std::vector >::iterator, std::vector >::iterator)':
Document.cpp:31:53: error: invalid operands of types 'void' and 'int' to binary 'operator+'
currLine = (lines.insert(currLine, begin, end)) + n;
^*
```

What is the problem?
Or maybe there is a better way to update my iterator to points the last element that added ?

Comment: the problem is that [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) with three parameters returns void.

Comment: oops, nope. missed that.

Comment: What g++ version are you using ? On [https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/z/Q-J8sd) it compiles fine since `g++4.9`. Upgrade your compiler.

Comment: I think @Thomas is correct... it's possible that you and your teacher are using different compilers.  Perhaps your teacher's compiler is somehow using an older, pre-C++11 version of the standard library, where the `insert` function returns `void`.

Comment: @rafix07 but that is the exact message for c++98 : [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5a5c053fc577a06)

Comment: @Thomas As I said in previous comment, OP should use 4.9 or higher, it is a bug - [link bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55817).

Answer (score 1):

For `G++` < `4.9` it is a bug. Link on bugzilla is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55817).

You can ugrade your compiler or use different approach for example based on index.

```
void Document::addLineBefore(
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator begin, 
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator end)
{
    if (begin != end)
    {
        int idx = std::distance(lines.begin(),currLine);
        idx += std::distance(begin,end) - 1;
        lines.insert(currLine, begin, end);
        currLine = lines.begin() + idx;
    }
}
```

1. Find index of `currLine` in vector.
2. Add width of inserted range to `idx`, and substract 1 (you want to point one element before old currLine).
3. Insert elems into vector.
4. Calculate iterator `currLine` based on `idx`.

[Live demo g++4.8](https://godbolt.org/z/sktgtg)